# Portal System in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am implementing a portal system in my game but there's a little bit problem. I have WorldInteraction script that attached to my player. Whenever the player collides on the portals, the player needs to hit the Enter Key to select a location. Now my question is why does I get too many logs in console (for testing purposes) after I hit the Enter Key? For example If I have 3 logs in console then my portal button will also be 3.

This what I'm talking about. See the screenshot below:
As you can see there are 3 logs in console and also the buttons are the same. How to fix that bug? It should be 1 button per map.

Portal:

[image]

Canvas:

[image]

Portals:

[image]

**WorldInteraction.cs**

```
public class WorldInteraction : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject messagePanel;

    private bool hasInteracted = false;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider interactedObject) {
        messagePanel.SetActive (true);
        if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Interactable Object") 
        {
            messagePanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "Press F to interact";
        }
        else if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Pickupable Object")
        {
            messagePanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Press Left Control to pick up";
        }
        else if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Portal")
        {
            messagePanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "Press Enter to select location";
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider interactedObject) {

        if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Interactable Object" && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F)) {
            hasInteracted = true;
            GetInteraction (interactedObject);
        }

        else if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Pickupable Object" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl)) {
            hasInteracted = true;
            GetInteraction(interactedObject);
        } 

        else if(interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Portal" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) {
            hasInteracted = true;
            GetInteraction(interactedObject);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit() {
        messagePanel.SetActive (false);
    }

    void GetInteraction(Collider interactedObject) {
        interactedObject.GetComponent<Interactable> ().MoveToInteraction ();
        messagePanel.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

**PortalController.cs**

```
public class PortalController : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private Button button;
    private Portal[] portal;
    private Player player;
    private GameObject panel;

    void Start() {
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player> ();
        panel = transform.Find ("PanelPortals").gameObject;
    }

    public void ActivatePortal(Portal[] portals) {
        panel.SetActive (true);
        for (int i = 0; i < portals.Length; i++) {
            Button portalButton = Instantiate (button, panel.transform);
            portalButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = portals [i].name;
            int x = i;
            portalButton.onClick.AddListener (delegate {
                OnPortalButtonClick (x, portals [x]);
            });
        }
    }

    void OnPortalButtonClick(int portalIndex, Portal portal) {
        player.transform.position = portal.TeleportLocation;
        foreach (Button button in GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()) {
            Destroy (button.gameObject);
        }
        panel.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

**Portal.cs**

```
public class Portal : ActionItem {
    public Vector3 TeleportLocation { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    private Portal[] linkedPortals;
    private PortalController portalController { get; set; }

    void Start () {
        portalController = FindObjectOfType<PortalController>();
        TeleportLocation = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }

    public override void Interact() {
        portalController.ActivatePortal(linkedPortals);
        Debug.Log ("Interacting with Portal");
    }
}
```

**Interactable.cs**

```
public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour {

    public virtual void MoveToInteraction() {
        Interact ();
    }

    public virtual void Interact() {
        Debug.Log ("Interacting with base class.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your script where you set up the location(s).

Comment: What's the point of the `hasInteracted` variable?

Comment: I edited my question. The hasInteracted variable, I think it will check if the player has interacted to that tag.

Comment: you didn't post code that listens to escape.

Comment: Where's the code that calls `somePortal.Interact();`? @JohnWinslow

Comment: I edited again the question. @nalka

Comment: Help me guys. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because Input.GetKeyDown was called in OnTriggerStay.  Input.GetKeyDown and functions like that are meant to be called in Update because the state's reset every frame.  Try moving it there.

Comment: I tried that. But how can I call the GetInteraction method inside the Update method? Since the GetInteraction method has a parameter.

Comment: void Update() {
  if (hasInteracted && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F)) {
   GetInteraction (interactedObject);
  }
 }

void OnTriggerStay(Collider interactedObject) {

  if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Interactable Object") {
   hasInteracted = true;
  }
}

This what I did. But I got this error: The name `interactedObject' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `code`

void Update() { 
 if (hasInteracted && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F)) {
  GetInteraction (interactedObject); 
 }
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider interactedObject) { 
 if (interactedObject.gameObject.tag == "Interactable Object") { 
  hasInteracted = true; 
 }
} 

`code`

Comment: If you need the Collider, you could have the OnTriggerStay method store it in a variable for the Update Function to retrieve when the key is pressed.

Comment: How? Help me please.

Comment: Where are you placing your Update method?  Because if you put it in your World Interaction class, you can declare a Collider variable in the same way that you declared hasInteracted and messagePanel.  Putting the Input.GetKeyDown in the wrong place affected a lot of your code, so you may have to restructure a lot.

Comment: Personally, the way I like to handle this is to have a variable that's changed when the player enters or exits the collider, and check that variable in Update when the key is pressed.

Comment: My Update method is in the WorldInteraction. The WorldInteraction script is attached to my player.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be much help without seeing your updated script.  Try tracing through it, and be mindful of what you have in OnTriggerEnter, Stay, and Exit.